# Extract values only from an array to encode them in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

This has probably been asked many times but I can't find a solution for my case.

This is my array :

```
$request=Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [staName] => Auditorium Stravinsky 2m2c ) 
        [1] => Array ( [staName] => Geneva Arena ) 
        [2] => Array ( [staName] => Les Docks ) 
        [3] => Array ( [staName] => Kheops ) 
    )
```

And i need an output as follows as JSON:

```
"Auditorium Stravinsky 2m2c ","Geneva Arena","Les Docks","Kheops"
```

My current code is as follows:

```
    foreach($request as $value)
    {
        $names[]=$value;
    }

    $jsonValue = json_encode(array_values($names));

    print_r($jsonValue);
```

And my current output is as follows in JSON format:

```
[{"staName":"Auditorium Stravinsky 2m2c "},{"staName":"Geneva Arena"},{"staName":"Les Docks"},{"staName":"Kheops"}]
```

How can i stop "staName " from being outputed?

Many thanks in advance and please be considerate of my post as this is only the second one I make on this site.

Comment: `$names[]=$value['staName'];`, you don't need to call `array_values()` either - or you could just do `$jsonValue = json_encode(array_column($request, 'staName'));`

Comment: @billyonecan Thank you! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$request=Array (
        0 => Array ( 'staName' => 'Auditorium Stravinsky 2m2c' ) ,
        1 => Array ( 'staName' => 'Geneva Arena' ) ,
        2 => Array ( 'staName' => 'Les Docks' ) ,
        3 => Array ( 'staName' => 'Kheops' )
    );


$newArray=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($request);$i++){
    $newArray[$i]=$request[$i]['staName'];
}

$newArray=json_encode($newArray,true);
print_r($newArray);
```

And the output is a merged json:

```
["Auditorium Stravinsky 2m2c","Geneva Arena","Les Docks","Kheops"]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, can't beleive it was so simple. I will mark you as the accepted answer in a few minutes when it is available

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this from,
**Code**

```
$a = array();
foreach($request as $key =>$val){
  foreach($val as $k => $v){
   $a[] = $v;
  }
}
print_r(json_encode($a));
```

Check this Demo [link](https://eval.in/901601)

**Output**

```
["Auditorium Stravinsky 2m2c","Geneva Arena","Les Docks","Kheops"]
```

Answer (score 0):

fist of all your `array` definition are not correct. and your output is simple string not a `JSON`

```
<?php

$request=Array ( 
        0 => Array ( 'staName' => 'Auditorium Stravinsky 2m2c' ), 
        1 => Array ( 'staName' => 'Geneva Arena' ) ,
        2 => Array ( 'staName' => 'Les Docks' ) ,
        3 => Array ( 'staName' => 'Kheops' ) 
    );

    $name = '';
    foreach($request as $value)
    {
        foreach($value as $value2)
        {
            $name = $name . ' ' . $value2;
        }

    }
    echo $name;
```

Output

```
Auditorium Stravinsky 2m2c Geneva Arena Les Docks Kheops
```